# UIView Returning Wrong Size

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, sprite-kit, swift2

I am trying to get the dimensions of the screen/UIView, however it returns a smaller area. Here is a picture to demonstrate:
[image]

Running all of this in a view controller:
Red dot position:

```
CGPointMake(0, 0)
```

Green dot position:

```
CGPointMake(self.view.bounds.width / 2, self.view.bounds.height / 2)
```

Blue dot position:

```
CGPointMake(self.view.bounds.width, self.view.bounds.height)
```

The distance from the red to the blue dot should be the diagonal of the screen. Does anyone know why it is not? Thanks!

Comment: Where are in your ViewController Life Cycle are you setting the CGPoints? Are you using AutoLayout?

Comment: @ezCoding I did it in viewDidLayoutSubviews() and I am not using AutoLayout AFAIK

Comment: Your view frame might be incorrect. Try adding a border around your view. self.view.layer.borderWidth = 1; self.view.layer.borderColor = [UIColor redColor].CGColor;

Comment: It put a border around the entire screen... Strange

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered the issue. The scale mode for the scene was causing strange results. I fixed it by playing around with the scale mode.